# Apache Camel: Notification on CamelContext stop

Tags: java, apache-camel

How can I get a notification when a CamelContext is stopped, the API has addStartupListener but nothing similar for when the context is stopped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question was also asked on the Camel mailing list
http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Notification-on-CamelContext-stop-tp5729300.html

There is several ways. One as Evgeniy Dorofeev shows with the lifecycle strategy.
http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/spi/LifecycleStrategy.html

And another is the event notifier which is using Event objects and has more events than the lifecycle strategy. For example as shown in this example: http://camel.apache.org/eventnotifier-to-log-details-about-all-sent-exchanges.html

And if you use Spring or Blueprint XML then you can configure them by defining a bean and Camel will pick it up as documented here: http://camel.apache.org/advanced-configuration-of-camelcontext-using-spring.html

Answer (score 2):

this is one of the ways

```
    camelContext.addLifecycleStrategy(new LifecycleStrategySupport() {
        @Override
        public void onContextStop(CamelContext context) {
        }
    });
```

see more in Claus Ibsen's answer, he is the author of Camel in Action http://www.manning.com/ibsen/